# How do I find the inode of any directory?

Tags: ls, inode

There is literally nothing on google that I can find that will help me answer this question. I presume it is passing some other parameter to `ls -i`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, the argument -i will print the inode number of each file or directory the ls command is listing.
As you want to print the inode number of a directory, I would suggest using the argument -d to only list directories.
For printing the inode number the directory /path/to/dir, use the following command line:

```
ls -id /path/to/dir
```

From `man ls`:

```
   -d, --directory
          list  directory entries instead of contents, and do not derefer‐
          ence symbolic links
   -i, --inode
          print the index number of each file
```

Answer (score 20):

This works also with stat:

```
DIR=/
stat -c '%i' $DIR
```

From [`man stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html):

```
   -c  --format=FORMAT
          use the specified FORMAT instead of the default; output  a  new‐
          line after each use of FORMAT
[...]

   The valid format sequences for files:    
       %i     inode number
```

Comment: I'd like to add that the **stat** command from [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=1), [NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?stat+1), [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=1) and [OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) works a bit differently and `stat -f '%i' $DIR` has to be used.

Answer (score 4):

You can find inode of file and directory with `-i` option

`ls -id /home/user/dir`

You can get information of consumed inode of your system

`df -hi`

Answer (score 1):

In c++:

```cpp
#include <sys/stat.h>

ulong getInode( const QString &path )
{
        struct stat st;
        stat( path.toUtf8(), &st );
        return st.st_ino;
}
```

This should work for files and folders.