# Is there a way to create file references that won't be broken when files and directories are renamed or moved?

Tags: shell

Is there a way to create file references that won't be broken when files and directories are renamed or moved? For example, references that refer to files by something like an inode rather than a name?

Comment: Dear Gavin, would you please provide an example for the problem that you have so we can help more efficiently.

Comment: See my [edits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/90054/fabby) is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, several ways.

1. Hard links: `ln file1 file2`. Now `file2` will be another name for `file1`, and no matter what you rename `file1` to, or even if you delete it, `file2` will always still work to access it (unless you rename/delete it too, obviously). This only works for files, not directories, and all of the links have to be on the same filesystem.
2. Bind mounts: `mount --bind file1 file2`. This works like hard links, except it works for directories too, and it doesn't have the same-filesystem restriction. The downside is it's a privileged operation, so you need to be root (or be in your own user and mount namespaces).
3. File descriptors: `exec {foo}</some/file`. Once you do that, `/proc/self/fd/$foo` will be a "magic" symlink to the file (it's "magic" in the sense that it won't break like regular symlinks would, and is possible because of the special /proc pseudo-filesystem). This works for both files and directories, doesn't need any special privileges, and is automatically inherited and usable by child processes. The downsides are that it only lasts until the process that did it exits, and that you don't have much control over the path to it.
4. [name_to_handle_at/open_by_handle_at](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open_by_handle_at.2.html): This meets your literal requirement, but is more complicated than any of the above and is a privileged operation. The only advantage is that the handle is regular data and doesn't require any state to be held.

Answer (score 0):

On an EXT filesystem you can use the `debugfs` command to recreate a link directly to an inode:

```
debugfs -w /dev/mapper/vg0-root -R 'link <16> myfile'
```

Which will create a "file" named myfile and pointing to inode 16.

However, if you delete that file, it'll still be gone, but if it's moved, it'll remain the same.

to get the inode of a file, [have a look here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121829/how-do-i-find-the-inode-of-any-directory)...

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178593/link-to-a-specific-inode)

Comment: You should only use `debugfs -w` on a FS that is not mounted. When you do that `link`, you're creating a new directory entry for that file as if you had done `ln /other/path/to/that/file myfile`, but not incrementing the link count for that file which means you end up with a fs in an inconsistent state. If you rm and directory entry for that file, the link count will decrease, if it drops to zero, the inode will be considered free even though there are still one directory entry pointing to it!

Comment: Bad idea? delete answer? @StéphaneChazelas